# Politicians talk too much

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

There's this sentence :
"some people think Chicago's nickname is from **politicians who talk too much**

I need to know what is the meaning of **politicians talk too much**

And why *politicians*?

Comment: The city is indeed windy. Wind is a lot of air moving, just like anyone who talks for a living without saying much of substance. Ever notice that diplomats who are not succeeding in negotiations say many words, like "We certainly have had a great meeting of the minds and are encouraged to continue this rewarding process with excellent and reasonable partners"?

Comment: @YosefBaskin how about an answer from you? You comment a lot, and often I think to myself that would be a rather good answer but instead someone has to pluck the courage and formulate an answer. I never know if the answer is original or inspired by you or Fumble's comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are too kind. My standards for "answers” are high. It takes me time to source for thoroughness and to incorporate humor - a must for me.

Comment: @YosefBaskin A comment sometimes only requires a little fleshing out and it becomes a perfectly respectable answer. But each to their own I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a joke.

"Politicians" are people who have an elected office in a legislature or senate (for example).  Their job involves lots of discussion. So they have to talk a lot. Some people think that politicians should talk less and be more practical.  They say that politicians talk too much, and that much of what they say should not be trusted.  A colloquial paraphrase would be that they are **full of hot air**.

"...who talk too much" is a relative clause that describes "politicians".

A slang term for a person who talks a lot is "windy".  Chicago is famous for its wind, and so its nickname is "The Windy City".

The joke is that the politicians in Chicago are "windy".

Comment: Hope you don’t object to my edits!

Comment: I love edits.<s></s>

Answer (score 2):

As @James K explains, it is a play on Chicago’s nickname, *The Windy City*, based on its particular weather, and on the metaphor of *wind* for (excessive) talk.

Some other examples of this metaphor, which is common in English, are

- ***wind bag*** (and ***gas bag***) for someone thought to talk too much, especially about subjects that are considered dull or about which they are not particularly knowledgeable,
- ***blowhard*** for someone who talks too much, particularly in a boastful or authoritative way, and
- as advice that uttering something might be unnecessary or in vain, ***Save your breath***.

Another metaphor with similar meaning is of a mechanical device. It gives us such examples as

- ***chatterbox***
- ***motormouth*** and
- of someone who is thought to repeat themselves incessantly, a ***broken record***. This image comes from the fact that a vinyl phonograph record, if marred by a scratch—so, technically, not quite broken—can cause the needle to jump up and then fall back on a spot already played, which results in an infinite audio loop.